# Authlogic causing all rails tests to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm building an app in Rails 3 using Authlogic for authentication. I have a User model with a database table and a user_session model without one

All of my tests fail, whether I run

> Error:
>        test_the_truth(UsersControllerTest):
>        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: 
>        user_sessions: DELETE FROM "user_sessions" WHERE 1=1

It's expecting user_session to have a table even though it inherits from Authlogic. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Authlogic docs? http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase

Comment: Have you done migration for test database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have defined properly test database in config/database.yml, then try `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and this took me a while to discover... the thing is Authlogic has no table in the database. When we create the sessions with Rails generate, this is creating also automatically a fixture, which of course will fail later since there is no table to fill data in. Solution: delete the fixture of user_sessions.

Read more about the problem [here](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/09/example-app-test-failures-from.html)